# How to change request url before making request in scrapy?

Tags: python, request, scrapy

I need to modify my request url before a response is downloaded. But I'm not able to change it. Even after modifying the request url using `request.replace(url=new_url)`, the `process_response` prints the non-modified url. Here's the code of the middleware:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    original_url = request.url
    new_url= original_url + "hello%20world"
    print request.url            # This prints the original request url
    request=request.replace(url=new_url)
    print request.url            # This prints the modified url

def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    print request.url            # This prints the original request url
    print response.url           # This prints the original request url
    return response
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you are modifying the `request` object in `process_request()` - you need to *return it*:

```
def process_request(self, request, spider): 
    # avoid infinite loop by not processing the URL if it contains the desired part
    if "hello%20world" in request.url: pass 

    new_url = request.url + "hello%20world"
    request = request.replace(url=new_url) 
    return request
```

Comment: It went into an infinite loop. But I got the flow now. I need to return the new request so that it can be processed. I used an `if` condition to check if the url is modified and then returned the request. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please post how you accomplished this? I've posted a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497430/keep-scrapy-spider-on-google-cache-of-site

Comment: @Rahul could you please update the answer or put into the comments what you ended up with? I do see that the current code in the answer causes an infinite loop - wanna fix/improve the answer.

Comment: I don't remeber it exactly, but it was something like this: `def process_request(self, request, spider): if "hello%20world" in request.url: pass else: new_url= request.url + "hello%20world" request=request.replace(url=new_url) return request`